# paging gridview that is loaded with csv file with more than 300 lines

Tags: asp.net, gridview, csv

How do I page without having program require user to reload file? Here is the code. Please steer me in right direction, or show me code example.

```
     protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName == string.Empty)
        {

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] FileExt = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.');
            string FileEx = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1];
            if (FileEx.ToLower() == "csv")
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(" " + FileUpload1.FileName));
            }
            else
            {

                return;
            }
        }
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
        string[] headers = reader.GetCSVLine();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (string strHeader in headers)
            dt.Columns.Add(strHeader);
        string[] data;
        while ((data = reader.GetCSVLine()) != null)
            dt.Rows.Add(data);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string dateAndTime = row["Date and Time"].ToString();
            string personName = row["Description #2"].ToString();
            string doorType = row["Card number"].ToString();

            DateTime dateEntered = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAndTime);
            DoorType doorTypeEnum;

            bool personExists = false;
            foreach (object name in EmployeeListBox.Items)
            {
                if (name.ToString() == personName)
                {
                    personExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!personExists)
            {
                EmployeeListBox.Items.Add(personName);

            }
            switch (doorType)
            {
                case "A02 - Rear Entrance":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearEntranceDoor;
                    break;
                case "B12 - Exterior Main Floor Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorMainFloorDoor;
                    break;
                case "B12 - Interior Main Floor Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorMainFloorDoor;
                    break;
                case "C13 - Rear Break Room Door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearBreakRoomDoor;
                    break;
                case "B02 - Exterior Basement Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor;
                    break;
                case "B02 - Interior Basement Man Trap":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorBasementDoor;
                    break;
                case "D01 - Managed Services Main door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesDoor;
                    break;
                case "D01 - Managed Services Big Door":
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesBigDoor;
                    break;
                default:
                    doorTypeEnum = DoorType.None;
                    break;
            }
            peopleEntering.Add(new PersonEntered(personName, dateEntered, doorTypeEnum));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < peopleEntering.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
            string personName = peopleEntering[i].PersonName;
            if (peopleEntering[i].DoorEntered == DoorType.RearEntranceDoor)
            {
                startDate = peopleEntering[i].DateOfEntry;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < peopleEntering.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (peopleEntering[j].DoorEntered == DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor && peopleEntering[j].PersonName == personName)
                    {
                        endDate = peopleEntering[j].DateOfEntry;
                    }
                }

            }
            workSpans.Add(new WorkSpan(personName, startDate, endDate));

        }
        if (IsPostBack )
        {
            this.csvReaderGv.DataSource = new DataTable();

            this.csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;
            this.csvReaderGv.DataBind();
        }

            } 




    protected void csvReaderGv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            EmployeeListBox.Visible = true;
            messagePanelBox.Visible = true;
            DateAndTime.Text = csvReaderGv.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            Description1.Text = csvReaderGv.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
            Description2.Text = csvReaderGv.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
            Cardnumber.Text = csvReaderGv.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;

            List<WorkSpan> listOfWorkSpans = new List<WorkSpan>();

            string personName = csvReaderGv.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < workSpans.Count; j++)
            {
                if (workSpans[j].PersonName == personName)
                {
                    listOfWorkSpans.Add(workSpans[j]);
                }
            }
        }



    }

    protected void EmployeeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string personName = EmployeeListBox.Items[EmployeeListBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();

            List<WorkSpan> listOfWorkSpan = new List<WorkSpan>();

            foreach (WorkSpan workSpan in workSpans)
            {
                if (workSpan.PersonName == personName)
                {
                    listOfWorkSpan.Add(workSpan);


                }
            }
            int b;
            b = Convert.ToInt32(csvReaderGv.Rows[0].ToString());
            csvReaderGv.DataSource = listOfWorkSpan;
            DateAndTime.Text = csvReaderGv.Rows[b].Cells[2].ToString();
            Description1.Text = csvReaderGv.Rows[b].Cells[3].ToString();
            Description2.Text = csvReaderGv.Rows[b].Cells[4].ToString();
            DateTime startDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(csvReaderGv.Rows[b].Cells[2].ToString());
            DateTime endDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(csvReaderGv.Rows[b].Cells[2].ToString());
            TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate;
            if (true)
            {
                keyedInHoursLbl.Text = difference.ToString();
                keyedInHoursLbl.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            { 
        }


}

    }

    protected void csvReaderGv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       csvReaderGv.DataSource = dt;
        csvReaderGv.DataBind();
    }
```

Please need assistance. Been staring at this problem, for days

Comment: All the event methods you are using  here are postback. Why do you check? And why are you binding the grid with empty new table?

Comment: this is why I ask this question, so you and others can help me out and show me where I am going wrong. I am new at this. Please show me what I can change. I am trying to page my gridview, but i am not sure how to put my datatable in session, need a example to get out of my brain fart.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67520/GridView-Paging-and-Sorting) is an example, [here](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource12-How-to-implement-paging-and-sorting-in-aspnet-Gridview-control.aspx) is another.